# Use variable declared in other events

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm not sure whether it is proper title or not. I declared a variable on click of button1 and now I want to use that same variable with its value declared on button2. Is it possible?

Button1 event code

```
Dim file As New System.IO.FileInfo(preUploader.PostedFile.FileName)
newname2 = file.Name.Remove((file.Name.Length - file.Extension.Length))
newname2 = (uniqueID.Text & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_ddMMyyhhmmss")) + file.Extension
preUploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../prescriptions/" + newname2))
```

In above code there is a variable declared. I want to use this variable on Button2 click with exact value created on button1 click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't but you can declare your variable in the top of your cod behind page like :

```
Public Class Page1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
```

and in button1 you can write :

```
file = New System.IO.FileInfo(preUploader.PostedFile.FileName)
        newname2 = file.Name.Remove((file.Name.Length - file.Extension.Length))
        newname2 = (uniqueID.Text & System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_ddMMyyhhmmss")) + file.Extension
        preUploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../prescriptions/" + newname2))
```

and same in button2 :

```
file = New System.IO.FileInfo(........)
```

Comment: or store data in the viewstate, session, cache, database that will act as your global variable.

Comment: Can you answer this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670875/facebook-google-login-for-asp-net-website. I Posted but not getting response.

Comment: Ok you can look my proposition