# Facebook & Google Login for asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook-login

For my asp.net website I was trying put feature of FB & Google Login. I found tutorial from [ASPSNIPPETS](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-FaceBook-account-in-ASPNet-Website.aspx). Now in this what I have done is If user click on Facebook Login button then It first authorize the user & get user details in panel. Then I put my code to check whether user already exist in my db or not. If not then it Inserts user & then put login code. My Problem is after executing first line of code it stops executing further so that It is unable to check whether user is logged in or not & so on. I think it may be because of redirect url which stops further codes o execute. How Can I eliminate this problem?

```
Protected Sub Login(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        FaceBookConnect.Authorize("user_photos,email", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split("?"c)(0))

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblId.Text) Then
            Dim query As String = "Select ID, email From users where ID=@id"
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblId.Text)
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows Then
                'Do Login Code here
                Try
                    Dim str As String = "select * from users where ID='" + lblId.Text + "';"
                    Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd2)
                    Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "users"
                    Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = lblId.Text
                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
                    welcome.Visible = True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex)
                End Try
            Else
                Try
                    Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO users (ID, DP, displayName) values('" + lblId.Text + "', '" + ProfileImage.ImageUrl.ToString + "', '" + lblName.Text + "')"
                    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
                    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
                    dr.Close()
                    command.CommandText = str1
                    command.Connection = con
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Response.Write(ex)
                End Try


                Dim con2 As New MySqlConnection("connectionstring")
                con2.Open()
                Dim cmd3 As New MySqlCommand("Select ID, email From users where ID=@id", con2)
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblId.Text)
                Dim dr2 As MySqlDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
                If dr2.HasRows Then
                    'Do Login Code here
                    Try
                        Dim str As String = "select * from users where ID='" + lblId.Text + "';"
                        Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(str, con2)
                        con2.Open()
                        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd3)
                        Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "users"
                        Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = lblId.Text
                        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Response.Write(ex)
                        con2.Close()
                    End Try
                    con.Close()
                End If

            End If
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can optimise your code :

```
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lblId.Text) Then
        Dim str As String = "select * from users where ID=@id"
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", lblId.Text)
        Dim da As New Common.DataAdapter(cmd2)
        Dim ds As New Data.DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            'Do Login Code here
            Try

                Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "users"
                Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = lblId.Text
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
                welcome.Visible = True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO users (ID, DP, displayName) values(@id, @img,@name)"
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
                cmd = New SqlCommand(req, con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@id", lblId.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@img", ProfileImage.ImageUrl.ToString))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@name", lblName.Text))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
            'After insertion you don't have to select  from database just send the parameters to cookies
            Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "users"
            Response.Cookies("chkusername").Value = lblId.Text
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)

        End If
        con.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: The second block is first checks whether user fetched from fb is exist in my database or not. If not then it first Insert it in table & then perform login. And If Data exist then it will not do Insert & directly login user. Now suppose If I put second block on another button click then this code works fine but I don't want users to click 2 times to login in  to my system. Because on first it will get users data from fb & then it stops executing further code & that is what my main my problem.

Comment: I stucked badly in this problem. Please help me if you can or suggest me if   my logic is wrong.

Comment: the seconde block i want  is :     Dim con2 As New MySqlConnection("connectionstring")
                con2.Open()  .................  i thanks that is duplicated ??

Comment: No it's not duplicated. I wrote it again because suppose if user not exist in db then it performs Insert query & straight after I want it to get login immediately after insert.

Comment: Why my code is not executing after user gets authorized & data gets fetched successfully?

Comment: Can't you answer me?

Comment: Before testing I need to know what changes you made. Because my problem was after user authorization code stopped debugging.

Comment: It's the same except my code is better optimised ,test it and tell me if always stop

Comment: Your code is mixture of sql & mysql syntax. Please check. & I got error in common.dataadapter & req (is not declared it may be inaccessible due to it's protection level)